# C++ Implementation and Header File Linking

Tags: c++

I'm pretty sure this is probably something simple because I've followed what other people have already done on this website but I keep getting linking errors regardless of how I set up my files and #includes. Its quite odd, any who here is my code.

These three files will not compile with g++ main.cpp Fraction.cpp.

I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Fraction::simplify(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in w2-TsJ6zT.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Fraction.h"

int main() {
     Fraction fraction;
     int num, den;
     fraction.simplify(num, den);
}
```

This is my Fraction.h

```
class Fraction{

private:

//Variables
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
public:

//Methods

void simplify(int numerator, int denominator);
};
```

And finally my Fraction.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Fraction.h"

void simplify(int numerator, int denominator){

//definition here

}
```

Any help and information is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I added some more info, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void simplify(int numerator, int denominator){

//definition here

}
```

should be

```
void Fraction::simplify(int numerator, int denominator){

//definition here

}
```

The way you defined it, `simplify` is a simple function in global scope while the second variant implements the member function `simplify` of `Fraction` previously declared in `Fraction.h`. The linking error tells you that you never implemented this method (because you actually implemented a new function with same name).

Comment: Thank!!!!!!!!!! You!!!!!!!!! Could you tell me what the theory is if you don't mind.

Comment: Awesome, I understand it now. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @John3136 It wouldn't let me for 12 minutes. Don't worry, I was waiting on it ;).